# Unity UI canvas not working with VR

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I have been trying to get a very simple demo of a native Unity UI canvas working with VR.

I have read the oculus blog post here: https://developer3.oculus.com/blog/unitys-ui-system-in-vr/ but i need to use the native unity UI as i want to redistribute the code without license worries.I followed this tutorial https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/virtual-reality/interaction-vr?playlist=22946 and downloaded the unity vr samples project from the asset store. In this they provide some scripts to place on the camera (VRInput and VREyeRaycaster) and some scripts to place on the target object (VRInteractiveItem and ExampleInteractiveItem).

When i apply the target scripts to a regular GameObject in the scene (e.g. a cube) the raycast works fine and the appropriate calls are made when fire1 is activated. When i try and do this for a canvas object (e.g. a button) - no hit is detected. I have tried placing the two target scripts (VRInteractiveItem and ExampleInteractiveItem) on the canvas, the image containing the button and the button itself and none work. What am i doing wrong? Why would it work on a regular gameobject and not on a UI canvas? I have made sure all my canvas elements have their raycast target boolean property ticked

EDIT:
It seems to work when i attach a box collider to the UI element, is this required? i thought it should just work with a GraphicsRaycaster attached. but the configuration below doesn't work (when box collider is disabled and graphics raycaster is enabled)

[image]

This is what is on my players camera:

[image]

I dont have a problem using box colliders if i have to but i wanted to take advantage of the UI buttons changes in highlighted and pressed color properties

Comment: be sure to use the right RayCaster

"There are two types of built-in ray caster in Unity’s UI system: the GraphicRaycaster (for Canvases) and the PhysicsRaycaster (for physics objects)."

The raycast you use for the cube will probably be a PhysicsRaycaster

Answer (score 3):

In Unity raycasting works only with game objects having colliders. Raycast returns true when it hits a collider. Without colliders there is nothing the ray can hit.

[Unity Physics.Raycast documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html)

Comment: Thanks, All I had to do was add the `Gvr Pointer Graphic Raycaster` script to get it to work in Daydream!

Answer (score 3):

I believe, for anyone just seeing this for the first time, a potential reason it is not working is because the canvas from the above picture is using a "Graphics Raycaster" element and not an "OVR Raycaster" element. The OVR Raycaster is meant to replace the graphics raycaster to connect Oculus to Unity UI.

Comment: Is there an example of detecting clicking a UI button with a OVRRaycaster somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the unity's UI in VR you might want to take a look at this asset: [VRTK](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/64131)

There are some examples of VR UI using controllers or camera targeting.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your canvas, you should have an option that is "Plane Distance" it's set to 100 , I change it to 0.5 and it works quite well.